# Give a background image an opacity value

Tags: css

I have a gray linen background image that I repeat to give the whole body a gray linen look. I'd rather it had a gold tinge to it , though, but I don't have a gold linen image to repeat. 
So I was thinking that perhaps I could give he body a gold background color and then apply some transparency to the background image but I'm not seeing any thing in CSS3 that will do that.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Please use google: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the whole page in a `<div>` with the `background-color: rgba(#, #, #, .#)` set to the RGBA for gold with the alpha (the `.#`) set to your preferred opacity level.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `opacity: 0.5` to the CSS of the background image that you would like to use.  Then, you would be able to add the different color behind it as you wish.

Comment: *"You could add opacity: 0.5 to the CSS of the background image that you would like to use"* Can you please show an example? I never heard this was possible. If you thought about creating an `overlay` element... than that's not clear from what you wrote because **NO**, you cannot add *opacity: 0.5 to the CSS of the background image*

Comment: I'm talking about doing something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/9abeL/  And another probably better example would be this: http://jsfiddle.net/9abeL/2/

Comment: It was simply a quick example to exhibit the opacity... I would spend more time working on it if I were to actually use that specific code.

Comment: hm right, but yes, that's one way to go, I'd just use a different styles.